# Why is $_POST empty when I can see the POST variables in firebug?

Tags: php, forms, expressionengine

I am posting a form in an expressionengine (1.6.8) template. I'm doing it using jquery but have tried an HTML form too - same result. The PHP superglobal $_POST is empty after posting the form, even though I have PHP enabled on my templates (on input for the template containing the form and output on the processing template) and can see the POST variables in firebug.

Can anyone suggest what might cause this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/select-locale/processing" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="test"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <a id="test" href="">link</a>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function(){
                    $('#test').bind('click', function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var path = "/select-locale/processing"
                        var form = $('<form/>');
                        form.attr("method", "post");
                        form.attr("action", path);
                         var field = $('<input></input>');

                        field.attr("type", "hidden");
                        field.attr("name", 'locale');
                        field.attr("value", 'NZ');

                        form.append(field);
                        $('body').append(form);

                        form.submit();
                    });
                });


            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server-side code (inherited, not my own) :

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);exit;
if ( ! isset($_POST['locale']))
{
    $locale = FALSE;

    $returnPage = "/";
}
else
{
    $locale = $_POST['locale'];

    $returnPage = $_POST['returnPage'];


}

if (isset($_GET['locale'])) {

    $locale = $_GET['locale'];
    $returnPage = "/"; 
?>
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="cklocale" value="<?php echo $locale;?>" seconds="2678400"}

{exp:session_variables:set name="userLocale" value="<?php echo $locale;?>"}  <?php
}
?>
{exp:cookie_plus:set name="cklocale" value="<?php echo $locale;?>" seconds="2678400"}

{exp:session_variables:set name="userLocale" value="<?php echo $locale;?>"}  


{exp:session_variables:get name="testSession"} 

{if  '{exp:session_variables:get name="testSession"}'=='yes' }
    {redirect="<?php echo $returnPage;?>"}
{if:else}
    {redirect="/nocookies/"}
{/if}
```

Comment: Not sure it seems like form is getting submitted twice because of either action attribute of form tag or oath value in jquery function

Comment: its an authorization secret key asked for identification, generally appended in url

Comment: for debugging, also check $_REQUEST array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- check the network tab if the parameters you want are really sent out
- check the url if it's correct
- if you use any sort of routing mechanism or url rewrite, you might wanna review it also
- check your validation and XSS rules (if any) as it may reject the whole array once hints of XSS is found.

happened to me a while ago (CI) and i was sending it to the wrong url

Comment: if the URL is wrong, how come I can see the output from a var_dump($_POST)?

Comment: Done but I solved the problem. The URL needed a trailing slash, presumably something to do with EE or sth in .htaccess was causing this.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to re-check the action attribute, are u sure you're sending the data to the right url? I doubt that anything could be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like form is getting submitted twice because of either action attribute of form tag or oath value in jquery function

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful

```
 <html>
     <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body name="test">
        <form action="/select-locale/processing" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="test"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        </form>
        <a id="test" href="">link</a>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    $('#test').bind('click', function(){
    var form ='<form action="/select-locale/processing" name="newform" method="POST"><input type="hidden1" name="locale" value="NZ"></form>';
    $('body').append(form);
    alert('added');
    document.newform.submit();
    });
});
</script>`
```